# Display Django Form Fields depending on option selected using Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am working on a Django Project and I have the following html page which renders a form.
I do not know much of Javascript, and I think I am going wrong somewhere in the Javascript Function or something else entirely.
What I need to do is render the "id_mapnubparam01" field only when value of "id_mapnubfunction" is 'GETDATA'. I've split the if condition into 2 just to be clear, the first if condition for the "p" tag works perfectly fine. However using the same if then else logic the "id_mapnubparam01" does not do anything. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("id_mapnubfunction").value;
      if (x != 'GETDATA') {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                          } else
                          {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
                          }
      if (x != 'GETDATA') {document.getElementById('id_mapnubparam01').hide();
                          } else
                          {document.getElementById('id_mapnubparam01').show();
                          }
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide() and show() are jquery function.

If you are running jquery, you'll need to treat the element as a jquery object:

```
$('#id_mapnubparam01').hide();
```

if you are not running jquery, try:

```
document.getElementById('id_mapnubparam01').style.display = "none"
```

and then set to "block" for show.

Comment: Thanks @SamSparx . This works for me. Is there a way to set the default style.display = "none" for the element when the page is loaded?

Comment: Usually you'd do something like that in a css file or <Style> tag if you must. `#id_mapnubaram01 {display:none;}`